# Grant usage access permission with MDM

Tags: android, android-permissions, mdm, airwatch

Is it possible to grant *usage access* permission with MDM on a managed device without user doing it manually?

Answer (score 0):

It has to be possible, because [the requirements for MDM](https://developers.google.com/android/work/requirements#4.2.-runtime-permission-grant-state-management) says:

> **4.2. Runtime permission grant state management**
>
> After setting a default runtime permission policy (see 4.1.), IT admins can silently set responses for specific permissions from any work app built on API 23 or above.
>
> 4.2.1. IT admins must be able to set the grant state (default, grant, or deny) of any permission requested by any work app built on API 23 or above. The EMM should enforce these settings via [policy](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies#PermissionPolicy).

In the list of permissions defined in Android, I found [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS) for *usage access* permission.

> **PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS**
>
> Added in API level 23
>
> Allows an application to collect component usage statistics
>
> Declaring the permission implies intention to use the API and the user of the device can grant permission through the Settings application.

I hope you can find a way to choose it in your MDM console. [This](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workspace-ONE-UEM/2001/Android_Platform/GUID-AWT-PROFILE-PERMISSIONS.html) might be the document for you, since your question is tagged with `airwatch`.